# Unexpectedly in 'private' folder when changing the working directory to a temp folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system, temp

I'm getting some unexpected results when trying to create and change the working directory to a temp folder with Node.js.

Here's some code:

```
var path = require('path')
var fse = require('fs-extra')
var TEST_DIR = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'mydir') // creates temp path
fse.emptyDirSync(TEST_DIR) // creates the dirs recursively
process.chdir(TEST_DIR) // changes the CWD
assert.equal(process.cwd(), TEST_DIR) // assert that these are the same
```

This is what's being returned:

```
 AssertionError: '/private/var/folders/jt/043tcrbs3m386w8kxjlf3jz00000gn/T/mydir' == '/var/folders/jt/043tcrbs3m386w8kxjlf3jz00000gn/T/mydir'
  + expected - actual

  -/private/var/folders/jt/043tcrbs3m386w8kxjlf3jz00000gn/T/recursive-deps
  +/var/folders/jt/043tcrbs3m386w8kxjlf3jz00000gn/T/recursive-deps
```

For some reason the `TEST_DIR` doesn't have the `private` prefix, and the CWD is prefaced within `private`. Whats happening here?

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: @skymk nope, still not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I suspect that there's a symlink in there somewhere. You can do something like this to get the actual path:

`var TEST_DIR = fs.realpathSync(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'mydir'))`